# Problem with Capital letter in my class name in R

Tags: r, class, oop

I'm a student in biology.
I have a problem with the class in R.
I have created this class: (this class is just a test, it do nothing)

```
Chromosome <- setRefClass('Chromosome',
                    fields = list(genes='list',genes_range='list',fitness='numeric'),
                    methods = list(get_fitness=function(object){
                      fitness <<- 2
                    },
                    mutate=function(object){
                      print('mutate')
                    })
                    )

a <- Chromosome(genes=list('just','a random value'),genes_range=list('lplpk',15),fitness=1)
```

and when i try to run this code I have this error:

```
Error in initialize(value, ...) : 
  invalid names for slots of class “Chromosome”: genes, genes_range, fitness
```

But if i replace the Chromosome by chromosome there is no problem.
Do you have any idea on why there is this problem?
Now the code works, but I still don't know why I can't use a 'C' for chromosome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not creating the object correctly. See here:

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/R5.html

You're missing the `$new` part:

```r
a <- Chromosome$new(genes=list('just','a random value'),genes_range=list('lplpk',15),fitness=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, with new it's all good.